# iOS Swift: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '() -> String?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '() -> String?

How to treat this error?

[image]
Code:

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let xibName = getXibName()

    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: xibName!, bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(
        withOwner: self,
        options: nil).first as? UIView
}

func getXibName() -> String? {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Please copy paste the code. You are free to post the screenshot to show the error you get. But please include a copy of the code, so that it is easier for people to respond using your code.

Comment: Better show your code also as text. Isn't that Xcode is digging old historic errors? Have you tried Clean Build Folder or restarting Xcode or restarting your Max?

Comment: Clean your code, Delete derived data or restart xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to OOPer's comment:

Xcode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder

[image]